# Convert NSObject to NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am about to change a part of my application over to CoreData. I have a custom class that I wrote that I want to convert to NSManagedObject. Before I go through all of this I would like to make sure that it will work. Do I just need to make an entity in the CoreData file and change the subclass? are there any other considerations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation is very useful on this point](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html). In particular, you want to read the part of that document named *'Subclassing Notes'*.

Things to consider would include: are you using any objects that are not supported by Core Data? If so, you'll want to either make them non-persistant, or if that isn't an option you'll want to look at implementing [non-standard persistent attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919)

The documentation I've linked to above should be pretty helpful: it's pretty clear and straightforward. To be honest it is difficult to tell how much of an effort it will be on your part: if your `NSObject` subclass is relatively simple it could be a very straightforward process. But if you're working with something more complex you will want to consider the points raised in the docs above.

Comment: Thanks I think that will help.